# iis site use 100% cpu

Tags: iis, iis-7, cpu, w3wp

I'm running iis7 under windows 2008 R2

The "w3wp.exe" process (the iis site) use 100%+- CPU

Is there any why I can check which part of the site cause the problem ?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052633/w3wp-exe-using-100-cpu-where-to-start

Answer (score 8):

In IIS 7 you can open IIS Manager and Use the Worker Processes feature, in that you will see the processes and the CPu they are consuming. If you double click the worker process that is consuming 100% cpu it will show you the list of requests that are running in that precise time, including how long they have been running and in which state they are. Usually that will show you the offending page.

Comment: steps to do this:
Open IIS Manager. 
In the Connections pane, select the server node in the tree.
In Features View, double-click Worker Processes.
View the list of worker processes in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

You could try attaching a debugger to w3wp, and hitting the Pause button in Visual Studio. You should, in theory, land at the place that's takin the longest to complete. Other than that, you'll have to implement some tracing.

Comment: I'm using classic asp3 code. any program that make this tracing that i can download?

Comment: Like I wrote in my answer, Visual Studio works. However, you need to follow certain steps: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikhailarkhipov/archive/2005/06/24/432308.aspx

Also, you could try using Visual Studio 2003 instead of latest & greatest. Let me kno wif it helps. Be sure to mark the answer helpful/upvote if it does.

Answer (score 0):

This happens every time we deploy one of our web sites. We recycle the App Pool that it runs in and it fixes the processor peg. Sometimes it takes a couple of times recycling but it works.